# Should I unbind event listener to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Here is my code:

```
// array of image data
var images = [
   {
      url: 'image.jpg'
   }
];

// function that loads image
var loadImage = function(imageObject) {
    imageObject.img = $('<img src="'+imageObject.url+'"/>').error(function() {
       // error event handler, that might not always fire
       imageObject.img.remove();
       imageObject.notLoaded = true;
    });
};

loadImage(images[0]);
```

My question is how to clean up images array? If I assign
   `images = null;`, will this clean up memory for all images? Should I unbind 'error' handler?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, If after function call I log `images[0].img` - it returns image object.

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I didn't read the function carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C/C++ (and others), JavaScript takes care of memory management and garbage collecting. Of course, removing unnecessary data will release some resources used by your browser/server and may slightly improve the overall performance, but this is not an obligation and there will be no memory leaking if you forget about it.

To clean up the array, you can set `images.length = 0`. `images` will be an empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably too late for the party, but stumbled on this issue by myself. Reply by @oleq is correct, but only if this was Vanilla JS.

jQuery 1.x keeps all events in `jQuery.cache` object, so you need to unbind it, to remove it from there.